# Change the color of x number of cells based on the numeric value from another cell (in multiple rows)

Tags: vba, excel

My question is basically the same as this one ([Change the color of x number of cells based on the numeric value from another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392097/change-the-color-of-x-number-of-cells-based-on-the-numeric-value-from-another-ce)) with one extra condition: for multiple rows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FigA7.png)

So on the left side, there's a column "PTO 2018 Total" (range= I3:I80) and I want to color each row (range= J3:S80) based on the number of the column I, like I manually did for the first two rows.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Why vba?  Conditional Formatting will do this nicely.

Comment: Have you tried looping through the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional formatting:

Use a formula rule with the formula:

```
=AND(COLUMNS($J1:J1)<=$I1,ISNUMBER($I1))
```

Applied to

```
=$J:$S
```

[image]

Comment: thank you sooo much!!!! I voted your answer but given that I have no reputation, my vote cannot be displayed public :(

Comment: If you found this correct you, and only you as the questioner, can click the check mark by the answer to mark as correct.